# In Rails development environment loops show full hash after each loop. How to turn this off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

when running `rails s` in development mode, Rails prints the full hash after each loop.

```
<%= @attributes.each do |a| %>
  <%= a %></br>
<% end %>
```

gives me

```
A
B
['A','B']
```

rather than just

```
A
B
```

How to turn this off?

Comment: `<% @attributes.each do |a| %>`

Comment: @Alex, you are my hero!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @attributes.each do |a| %>
  <%= a %></br>
<% end %>
```

Remove the additional `=` from `<% @attributes.each do |a| %>`.

Adding `=` in `<%= .... %>` means that you want to display the output.

Side note, this will also work in any environment and not just development